# How to intersect results after GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

To illustrate my problem I have created this simple snippet. I have a class `Item`

```
public class Item
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public int StrategyID { get; set; }

    public List<Item> SeedData()
    {
        return new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {GroupID = 1, StrategyID = 1 },
            new Item {GroupID = 2, StrategyID = 1 },
            new Item {GroupID = 3, StrategyID = 2 },
            new Item {GroupID = 4, StrategyID = 2 },
            new Item {GroupID = 5, StrategyID = 3 },
            new Item {GroupID = 1, StrategyID = 3 },
        };
    }
}
```

And what I want to check is that this `SeedData` method is not returning any duplicated `GroupID/StrategyID` pairs.

So in my `Main` method I have this:

```
Item item = new Item();
var data = item.SeedData();

var groupByStrategyIdData = data.GroupBy(g => g.StrategyID).Select(v => v.Select(gr => gr.GroupID)).ToList();

for (var i = 0; i < groupByStrategyIdData.Count; i++)
{
    for (var j = i + 1; j < groupByStrategyIdData.Count; j++)
    {
             Console.WriteLine(groupByStrategyIdData[i].Intersect(groupByStrategyIdData[j]).Any());
    }
}
```

which is working fine but one of the problems is that I have lost the `StrategyID` so in my real-case scenario I won't be able to say for which `StrategyID/GroupID` pair I have duplication so I was wondering is it possible to cut-off the `LINQ` to here:

```
var groupByStrategyIdData = data.GroupBy(g => g.StrategyID)
```

and somehow perform the check on this result?

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for. In your example there are no two paris of GroupID/StrategyID that have the same values, but your code returns true for the second group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the very easy ways would be to do grouping using some identity for your Item. You can override Equals/GetHashCode for your Item or instead write something like:

```
Item item = new Item();
var data = item.SeedData();

var duplicates = data.GroupBy(x => string.Format("{0}-{1}", x.GroupID, x.StrategyID))
                        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                        .Select(group => group.Key)
                        .ToList();
```

Please note, that using a string for identity inside of group by is probably not the best way to do grouping.

As of your question about "cutting" the query, you should also be able to do the following:

```
var groupQuery = data.GroupBy(g => g.StrategyID);
var groupList = groupQuery.Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
var groupByStrategyIdData = groupQuery.Select(v => v.Select(gr => gr.GroupID)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, your first option looks nice but for some reason even if there are duplicated pairs the `duplicates` is still empty.

Comment: Even if you evaluate it to a list by adding ".ToList()" in the end?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it another way, as follows:

```
// Check for duplicates
if (data != null)
{
    var grp =
        data.GroupBy(
            g =>
                new 
                { 
                    g.GroupID,
                    g.StrategyID
                },
            (key, group) => new 
                { 
                    GroupID = key.GroupID,
                    StrategyId = key.StrategyID,
                    Count = group.Count() 
                });


    if (grp.Any(c => c.Count > 1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate exists");
        // inside the grp object, you can find which GroupID/StrategyID combo have a count > 1
    }
}
```